# Cypress Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "#8". Use "attach()" first

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing, vee-validate

I have simple test. All it does is providing data in input filed and send them:

```js
  it('Try to change email', () => {

    cy.login({email: Cypress.env('basicemail'), password: Cypress.env('changepassword')})
    cy.wait(2500)
    cy.get('nav > .account-info > div > img').click()
    cy.get('aside > ul > :nth-child(5) > a').click()
    cy.wait(2500)

    cy.get('a').contains('Change email').click()

    cy.get('input[name="newEmail"]').clear().type(Cypress.env('changeemail'))
    cy.get('input[name="newEmailConfirm"]').clear().type(Cypress.env('changeemail'))
    cy.get('input[name="changeEmailPassword"]').clear().type(Cypress.env('changepassword'))

    cy.get('a').contains('Confirm').click()
    cy.get(':nth-child(5) > .settings-modal-wrapper > .button').click()

    // HERE IS ERROR
    cy.get('.modal-description').contains(`Email with confirmation link has been sent to ${Cypress.env('changeemail')}. Please follow instruction from the email.`)

    cy.get('.modal-header > img').click()
    cy.get('aside > ul > :nth-child(7) > a').click()
  })
```

And after it click the button, I get 3 those error:

`Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "#8". Use "attach()" first.`

`Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "#9". Use "attach()" first.`

`Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "#10". Use "attach()" first.`

Actually, I have no idea, what it means, I was trying to find it out, but there is no info on that.

Here is how it looks like in console:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Off topic, there must be a way to remove those explicit `.wait(2500)`. Maybe add an  assertion like `.should('be.visible')` to the following element you click on?  Also, `.contains(selector, text)` can replace a few of your `.get()` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem. Actually it wasn't even about front, but about my API.

The problem is cypress removes all from `localStorage` when visits other page, so I had to do some actions to save it in `localStorage` - login one more time.

So, be careful with this, problem could be in API, not front.